# How to get Paypal 'Add to Cart' button response?

Tags: php, paypal

I m trying to add a Paypal `Add to cart` button in my application. For that i create code from paypal sanbox. This is my form,

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="EGZD52TPWUERY">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Fees">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="255">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="85.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="my-application/paypal/success">
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="0.000">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id_<?php echo $res_1->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $res_1->id; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHosted">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

The payment transaction is completed successfully and the redirect is done perfectly to my application. But the problem is i didn't get any response in that page. I tried `var_dump($_POST)`. It retruns `null`. Don't know why i didn't get any response. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use "var_dump($_GET)" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following link and update your paypal account.The response is in `$_GET`

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/

Comment: Now i get the response in `$_GET` method. Configured the auto response in the Paypal settings. thanks a lot...:)